# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' from input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a hidden input field like

```
<input type="hidden" name="product-data" value="{Product: 'Premium', Code: 'ER412', SalesCode: 'SC415', Description: 'Premium Product Details'}" />
```

on click of a button I am trying to convert this value into JSON object but getting error. Here is my js code

```
$('.icon-edit').live('click', function(){

        var data = $(this).parent().siblings('input').val();
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // <--- Here I am getting error
        //do something with data

    });
```

Error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'
```

Comment: `parseJSON` parses JSON. Are you trying to do the opposite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON property names are strings, and JSON strings are delimited by `"` characters.

Your property names are identifiers, and where you have string values, you have delimited them with `'`. This is fine for a JavaScript object literal, but not for JSON.

```
<input 
    type="hidden" 
    name="product-data" 
    value="{&quot;Product&quot;: &quot;Premium&quot;, &quot;Code&quot;: &quot;ER412&quot;, &quot;SalesCode&quot;: &quot;SC415&quot;, &quot;Description&quot;: &quot;Premium Product Details&quot;}" 
/>
```

(You could also delimit the HTML attribute value with `'` and use literal `"`s inside it)